# Trying to find a name given a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This is my code that will lead up to the question below.

[image]

**QN: I wish to find name that has the lowest duration_ms**

First, I attempted to use `.min()` to find the lowest duration_ms. Then I tried to get the name from there as shown in the picture below.

I got an error ***invalid index to scalar variable***

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please refrain from posting code as screenshots - use the code environment by indenting your code by 4 spaces (or copy/past/select it and hit **{}**) to indent all selected lines by 4 spaces. Reasoning: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one value of minimum create index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and use [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
min_name = df.set_index('name')['duration_ms'].idxmin()
```

If possible multiple values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare by minimum:

```
min_name = df.loc[df['duration_ms'] == df['duration_ms'].min(), 'name']
```